I encounter a connection failure every time I attempt to establish a peer-to-peer connection
WebRTCExampleOld :
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webrtc/flutter_webrtc.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class WebRTCExampleOld extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebRTCExampleOldState createState() => _WebRTCExampleOldState();
}

class _WebRTCExampleOldState extends State<WebRTCExampleOld> {
  RTCPeerConnection? peerConnection;
  String? streamId;
  String? sessionId;
  Map<String, dynamic>? offer;
  List<dynamic>? iceServers;
  String apiKey = 'Basic aGFrb2JhbDY0NEBqYWRzeXMuY29t:ga1wdyF-TLegS74bJWxbb';

  Future<void> startStream() async {
    try {
      RTCSessionDescription sessionClientAnswer = await createPeerConnection1();

      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://api.d-id.com/talks/streams/$streamId/sdp'),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': apiKey,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        // 'answer': {"type": offer!['type'], "sdp": offer!['sdp']},

        body: jsonEncode({
          'answer': {
            'type': sessionClientAnswer.type,
            'sdp': sessionClientAnswer.sdp,
          },
          'session_id': sessionId,
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("sdp api response==> ${response.body}");
      } else {
        print("sdp error ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error during streaming setup: $e');
      stopAllStreams();
      closePC();
    }
  }

  Future<RTCSessionDescription> createPeerConnection1() async {
    if (peerConnection == null) {
       Map<String, dynamic> configuration = {
        'iceServers': iceServers,
      };

 

      peerConnection = await createPeerConnection(configuration);

      peerConnection!.onIceGatheringState = (RTCIceGatheringState state) {
        print('ICE==> gathering:- $state');
      };

      peerConnection!.onIceCandidate = (RTCIceCandidate candidate) {
        print('ICE==> candidate:- ${candidate.candidate}');
      };

      peerConnection!.onIceConnectionState = (RTCIceConnectionState state) {
        print('ICE==> Ice connection state:- $state');
      };

      peerConnection!.onConnectionState = (RTCPeerConnectionState state) {
        print('ICE==> connection state:- $state');
      };

      peerConnection!.onSignalingState = (RTCSignalingState state) {
        print('ICE==> Signaling state:- $state');
      };

      peerConnection!.onTrack = (RTCTrackEvent event) {
        print('ICE==> track:- ${event.track}');
      };
    }

    await peerConnection!.setRemoteDescription(
        RTCSessionDescription(offer!['sdp'], offer!['type']));

    RTCSessionDescription sessionClientAnswer =
        await peerConnection!.createAnswer();
    await peerConnection!.setLocalDescription(sessionClientAnswer);

    return sessionClientAnswer;
  }

  void onIceGatheringStateChange() {
    // Implement your logic here
  }

  void onIceCandidate(RTCIceCandidate candidate) {
    // Implement your logic here
  }

  void onIceConnectionStateChange() {
    // Implement your logic here
  }

  void onConnectionStateChange() {
    // Implement your logic here
  }

  void onSignalingStateChange() {
    // Implement your logic here
  }

  void onTrack(RTCTrackEvent event) {
    // Implement your logic here
  }

  void closePC() {
    peerConnection?.close();
    peerConnection = null;
  }

  void stopAllStreams() {
    // Implement stopping all streams
  }

  Future<void> startTalkStream() async {
    stopAllStreams();
    closePC();

    final url = Uri.parse('https://api.d-id.com/talks/streams');
    final headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': apiKey,
    };
    final body = jsonEncode({
      'source_url':
          "https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/crash-girl-imaged-hd-background-girl-model-smart-hones-normal-cut-girl-queen-girl-imag_88650-3201.jpg",
    });

    final response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body);
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      print("responseData==> ${response.body}");

      setState(() {
        offer = responseData['offer'];
        iceServers = responseData['ice_servers'];
        streamId = responseData['id'];
        sessionId = responseData['session_id'];
      });

      await startStream();
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Stream started successfully!')),
      );
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Failed to start stream.')),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: startTalkStream,
              child: const Text('Start Stream'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


flutter ( 3790): ICE==> Signaling state:-
RTCSignalingState.RTCSignalingStateHaveRemoteOffer
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> track:- Track(id: janusa, kind: audio,
label: audio, enabled: true, muted: false)
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> track:- Track(id: janusv, kind: video,
label: video, enabled: true, muted: false)
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal:
initPlayout(sampleRate=48000, channels=1, bufferSizeFactor=1.0)
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal:
byteBuffer.capacity: 960
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal:
minBufferSizeInBytes: 7688
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal:
createAudioTrackBeforeOreo
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal:
nativeOutputSampleRate: 48000
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrack:
session ID: 273, channels: 1, sample rate: 48000, max gain: 1.0
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrack:
buffer size in frames: 3844
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrack:
buffer capacity in frames: 3844
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): VolumeLogger: start@[name=worker_thread

3991, id=2199]

I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): VolumeLogger: audio mode is:
MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: startPlayout
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): VolumeLogger: VOICE_CALL stream volume: 1
(max=6)
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal:
AudioTrackThread@[name=AudioTrackJavaThread, id=2204]
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal:
doAudioTrackStateCallback: 0
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): NetworkMonitor: Start monitoring with
native observer 516000207584 fieldTrialsString:
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 3790): onIceGatheringChangeGATHERING
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> Signaling state:-
RTCSignalingState.RTCSignalingStateStable
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: Network handle:
432902426637 becomes available: 100
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 3790): onConnectionChangeCONNECTING
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 3790): onIceCandidate
I/chatty  ( 3790): uid=10596(com.example.d_id_live_stream)
signaling_threa identical 1 line
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 3790): onIceCandidate
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: handle:
432902426637 capabilities changed: [ Transports: WIFI Capabilities:
INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED
LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps
SignalStrength: -56]
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> Ice connection state:-
RTCIceConnectionState.RTCIceConnectionStateChecking
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> gathering:-
RTCIceGatheringState.RTCIceGatheringStateGathering
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: handle:
432902426637 link properties changed
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> connection state:-
RTCPeerConnectionState.RTCPeerConnectionStateConnecting
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> candidate:- candidate:3100438455 1 udp
2122260223 192.168.1.18 38047 typ host generation 0 ufrag YXta
network-id 3 network-cost 10
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> candidate:- candidate:1633373584 1 udp
2122129151 127.0.0.1 39470 typ host generation 0 ufrag YXta network-id
1
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> candidate:- candidate:965035993 1 udp
2122202367 ::1 44733 typ host generation 0 ufrag YXta network-id 2
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 3790): onIceCandidate
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 3790): onIceCandidate
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> candidate:- candidate:2683410692 1 tcp
1518149375 127.0.0.1 48285 typ host tcptype passive generation 0 ufrag
YXta network-id 1
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> candidate:- candidate:3341783885 1 tcp
1518222591 ::1 47789 typ host tcptype passive generation 0 ufrag YXta
network-id 2
I/flutter ( 3790): sdp api response==>
{"session_id":"AWSALB=t5qyzsQBKcZyCffT4PDCSbZ1CI3D3qKin1qYPdYwFJX9MIktYfl8EOhE27XBo7dsMQlJckYyT9/1M2nVnJX9TnizJwSc4iF+0bqdzgH1gk86oAl8MMk6c1JkE5oJ;
Expires=Thu, 20 Jun 2024 10:25:55 GMT; Path=/;
AWSALBCORS=t5qyzsQBKcZyCffT4PDCSbZ1CI3D3qKin1qYPdYwFJX9MIktYfl8EOhE27XBo7dsMQlJckYyT9/1M2nVnJX9TnizJwSc4iF+0bqdzgH1gk86oAl8MMk6c1JkE5oJ;
Expires=Thu, 20 Jun 2024 10:25:55 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure"}
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 3790): onIceCandidate
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> candidate:- candidate:1923957892 1 udp
8331263 35.89.1.97 64716 typ relay raddr 43.250.156.0 rport 19315
generation 0 ufrag YXta network-id 3 network-cost 10
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 3790): onIceCandidate
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> candidate:- candidate:1923957892 1 udp
8331519 35.89.1.97 54311 typ relay raddr 43.250.156.0 rport 19189
generation 0 ufrag YXta network-id 3 network-cost 10
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 3790): onConnectionChangeFAILED
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> Ice connection state:-
RTCIceConnectionState.RTCIceConnectionStateFailed
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> connection state:-
RTCPeerConnectionState.RTCPeerConnectionStateFailed
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 3790): VolumeLogger: VOICE_CALL stream volume: 1
(max=6)
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 3790): onIceGatheringChangeCOMPLETE
I/flutter ( 3790): ICE==> gathering:-
RTCIceGatheringState.RTCIceGatheringStateComplete

How to Solve this error?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When I tap the button to start the peer connection, it shows "RTCPeerConnectionStateConnecting". After some time, it changes to "RTCIceConnectionStateFailed". I want to establish the peer connection successfully
